# django error returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, django

I'm uploading a file from Django web-site to my WordPress.

```
from subprocess import check_call
    try:
        check_call(['scp', filename, upload_filename])
         ....
    except (CalledProcessError, OSError):
        report['error_messages'].append("4 %s" % exc_info()[1])
        return report
```

This gives error:

> Command '['scp', '/uploads/test-01.txt',
>   'mysite.com:/home/wp-content/uploads/test-01.txt']' returned non-zero
>   exit status 1

Now,
If I do it manually from the console:

```
scp /uploads/test-01.txt mysite.com:/home/wp-content/uploads/test-01.txt
```

it's working:

```
test-01.txt  100% 0  0.0KB/s 00:00
```

(It's an empty file so 0 KB)

I don't understand why the scp fails from the Django. The error is not clear. What can I do?

Comment: Try putting in a line of text into the file, does the same thing happen?

Comment: @postoronnim what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you temporarily change your code to use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `check_call`, then you can capture the standard error.

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT

try:
    check_output(['scp', filename, upload_filename], stderr=STDOUT)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)  # output from STDERR should show what is going wrong
```

This should give you a hint what is going wrong. It could be permissions, if the Django website is running as a different user than you when you tested the command in the console.

Comment: When I add this nothing happens. it doesn't even show the previous error.  My django is very old could it be related?

Comment: If Django is not logging the `print` statement, you might have to change that, but otherwise the version of Django should make no difference. The code above is all from the Python standard library.

Comment: I changed it as follows: `from subprocess import check_call,check_output, CalledProcessError, STDOUT
    try:
        check_output(['scp', filename, upload_filename],stderr=STDOUT)
         ....
    except (CalledProcessError, OSError):
        report['error_messages'].append("4 %s, %s" % (CalledProcessError.output ,exc_info()[1]))
        return report` and nothing happens, it doesn't seem to know how to do it...

Comment: That's very different to my code above. You have not assigned the exception to the variable `e` as I did - `except CalledProcessError as e:`. Then your code is trying to access `CalledProcessError.output` instead or `e.output`.

Comment: same thing. nothing happens. I don't see anything.

Comment: I can't help since there is no error message to debug. Hope you figure out the problem.